# Failed to bounce to type inFirebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://platformapps.firebaseio.com/sensedb/platformdb/MESSAGES");

myFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            BlogPost user = userSnapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
        Log.d("Response", "Response");


    }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BlogPost {

    private String NOTIF_INST;
    private String NOTIF_TYPE;
    private String OBJ_DATA;
    private String OBJ_TYPE;

    public BlogPost() {

    }

    public String getNOTIF_INST() {
        return NOTIF_INST;
    }

    public void setNOTIF_INST(String NOTIF_INST) {
        this.NOTIF_INST = NOTIF_INST;
    }

    public String getNOTIF_TYPE() {
        return NOTIF_TYPE;
    }

    public void setNOTIF_TYPE(String NOTIF_TYPE) {
        this.NOTIF_TYPE = NOTIF_TYPE;
    }

    public String getOBJ_DATA() {
        return OBJ_DATA;
    }

    public void setOBJ_DATA(String OBJ_DATA) {
        this.OBJ_DATA = OBJ_DATA;
    }

    public String getOBJ_TYPE() {
        return OBJ_TYPE;
    }

    public void setOBJ_TYPE(String OBJ_TYPE) {
        this.OBJ_TYPE = OBJ_TYPE;
    }

}
```

[image]

This Exception coming 
  Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class info.androidhive.tendigimrapp.model.BlogPost] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method
            at

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing both your `BlogPost` class and the JSON you're trying to read with it, it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: Ok wait i am showing

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/BmpdAVfCciWG4YzncKbg4G  please check and tell me where is issue

Comment: Edit your question and include the information. Also: that doesn't contain the jSON yet. You can easily get the JSON from your Firebase dashboard by clicking the Export button.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/RbpQhhuWvDg9Gxv46gfRaa  this is Blog Post class and

Comment: No screenshots of JSON please, just grab the text by clicking Export in your Firebase dashboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107590/discussion-between-research-development-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 0):

Your getters are wrong for the properties you have in your JSON. In fact, I don't think there is a decent way to map this JSON to a Java Bean.

The only thing I can come up with is to bypass the Java Bean notation and go for:

```
public static class OneProperty {
    public String NOTIF_TYPE;
    // TODO: add other fields
}
```

While this is a simpler format and allows parsing of your JSON structure, it is essentially the equivalent of a C struct.

Comment: u mean i have to make BlogPost class with static